# Error Getting Website with Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, http-status-code-504

I'm trying to get a website through Scrapy in the shell,

```
$ scrapy shell -s NAME="Mozilla/5.0" "http://www.yapo.cl/chile/inmuebles?ca=15_s&l=0&cmn=&st=a"

2017-08-21 20:55:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.yapo.cl/chile/inmuebles?ca=15_s&l=0&cmn=&st=a> (failed 3 times): 504 Gateway Time-out
```

but Scrapy through me a 504 error which I cannot figure out, any guess what could it be?.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to set user agent string on command line, but using wrong setting (`NAME`). Try it with:

```
$ scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0" "http://www.yapo.cl/chile/inmuebles?ca=15_s&l=0&cmn=&st=a"
```

Like that, I get:

```
2017-08-22 07:40:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.yapo.cl/chile/inmuebles?ca=15_s&l=0&cmn=&st=a> (referer: None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were banned or something like that. Try using another ip address.
On my computer it gives this:

```
2017-08-22 00:07:43 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.yapo.cl/chile/inmuebles?ca=15_s&l=0&cmn=&st=a> (referer: None) ['partial']
```